# WebSocket Certificate on Mono (Mac, C#)

Tags: c#, macos, ssl, mono

I am trying to create some sort of Push manager, client side, that will listen to what the server has to say.

Nothing hard so... I have written it PC side, thanks to WebSocket4Net, on C#, and it works perfectly.

But here is the issue...: my application has to work on Mac too, using the same code. I use Mono obviously, and the WebSocket4Net lib works. Unfortunately, every time I try to open a socket, I have a nice "`RemoteCertificateNotAvailable`", followed by a "`Invalid certificate received from server`".

Here is what I have tried, following some advices from the web:

```
webSocket.AllowUntrustedCertificate = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = callbackValidation;
```

The code is basic and looks like the one on the web site of the lib: https://websocket4net.codeplex.com

I don't know why these solutions do not work. Other posts say this should work, and I have no idea why it doesn't here.

It CAN work by manually adding trusted certificates to Mono (mozroots --import --sync), or with certmgr, or something like that. But I don't want this solution, as it needs to work on any other computer than mine without installing anything.
I can accept running some command in my application that will install some certificates... Let's say I am interested in these solutions.
But I would rather find a solution implying some lines of C# code.

So... Does anyone have an idea on how to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Okay the creator of the WebSocket4Net lib did a fix in august for that actually.
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback works now.